# Why is it not returning a function?

Tags: c, function, return, scanf

I'm  writing a program for converting temperatures and I have most of it written. When I compile and run the program, it doesn't do the calculations, doesn't seem to recognise the `C`/`F` choice and it isn't working out the reset part either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

float promptTemp(float kelvin)
{
    printf("Please enter a sample temperature in degrees Kelvin:\n");

float convertFahrenheit(float temp)
{

    }while(reset == 'y');

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: C variables are passed by value. Which means any changes to variables passed into a function are not seen by the caller when the function returns. You either need to return a value from each function or pass in a pointer to variables that you want to store values into.

Comment: @AlanAu I think you meant to say C variables are passed by value.

Comment: @interjay Indeed. Finger and brain were not connected. Corrected now. Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: There's no need for a parenthesis around the return statement. It just makes the code look strange.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is

```
promptTemp(temp);
```

and

```
promptConvert(convert);
```

you're neither

- passing the pointer to variables as argument
- collecting the `return` value.

So,

```
 if(convert == 'c')
```

is esseentially using (reading) an uinitialized variable `convert` which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: .....I can't believe I didn't see that. I've been staring at it for 45 minutes. Thank you so much, Sourav!

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the values of the variables from your main function are changing inside your functions, because you are only passing a copy, and only that copy is modified inside the function and then lost. ( even though they have the same name ).

Try to pass the parameters as references or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the return value of the function in the main function:

```
promptTemp(temp);/promptConvert(convert);
```

try result =  promptTemp(temp);

and also you are not passing anything to the 
    **promptTemp()** function

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be modified:

```
   promptConvert(convert);
```

It isn't doing anything to `convert` variable. If you want the value returned from the function to be stored in the function, do this:

```
   convert = promptConvert(convert);
```

If you want the function to modify the value of variable passed to it, do this:

```
   char promptConvert(char &convert)   //pass by reference
```

Similarly for other functions, like:

```
   temp = convertCelsius(temp);
```

or

```
   float convertCelsius(float &temp)
```

There are other functions which need the same modification too, like `float convertFahrenheit(float temp)`

Answer (score 0):

By using a decent compiler, all the problems in this code will be revealed. One example of such a compiler is GCC. Get that one and then use it properly:

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

Compiler output:

```
C:\tmp>gcc test.c -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
test.c: In function 'promptConvert':
test.c:17:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     tolower(convert);
     ^
test.c: In function 'promptReset':
test.c:72:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     tolower(reset);
     ^
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:87:9: warning: 'temp' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitial
ized]
         promptTemp(temp);
         ^
test.c:89:9: warning: 'convert' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninit
ialized]
         promptConvert(convert);
         ^
test.c:100:9: warning: 'reset' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuniniti
alized]
         promptReset(reset);
         ^
```

So in addition to the bugs already pointed out in other answers, you also don't store the return value of tolower(). Should have been `convert = tolower(convert);`